# Why do tides reach a peak two days after the solar eclipse?

Tags: tidal-forces

On June 21st we, in India, experienced a total solar eclipse. Based on my basic understanding of why tides occur, the tidal forces by moon and sun add up and the tides will be maximum on the day of eclipse.

But to my surprise, tides kept on rising for next two days and reached a maximum on June 23rd.

[image]

It doesn't make much sense to me. Can anyone please clarify.

Comment: Tides are complicated. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121830/123208 David Hammen's answer there is very thorough, and contains several helpful diagrams, some animated.

Comment: All sorts of things cause delays as well as summed-amplitudes in ocean heights (tidal).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: What are "all sorts of things"?

Comment: Any book/reference where I can read about various factors affecting oceanic tides?

Comment: I'd say this question is getting into Earth Science territory. Here's an equivalent question on the Earth Science stack exchange: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/why-dont-spring-tides-occur-at-full-new-moon-age-of-tide